# i got segmentation fault i dont understand way

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, malloc

I have a task to create a compiler
I have now listed here two functions in which the problem was created.
And below I gave the output it gives with prints
When I call the cond3AC function in a row

```
s_3AC * e1 = cond3AC (tree-> childrens [0]);
```

I get segmentation fault

If you try to keep track of prints I get allocation properly and return everything properly.

```
s_3AC* Exp3AC(node *tree){
     if(!strcmp("&&", tree->token) || !strcmp("||", tree->token) || !strcmp("==", tree->token) || !strcmp("!=", tree->token)|| 
        !strcmp(">", tree->token) || !strcmp(">=", tree->token) || !strcmp("<", tree->token) || !strcmp("<=", tree->token)){           
        red();
        printf("######## check now the e2 ########## \n");
        printf("check token right: %s\n",tree->childrens[1]->token);
        s_3AC* e2 = cond3AC(tree->childrens[1]);
        printf("e2 -> %s\n", e2->code);

        purple();
        printf("######## check now the e1 ########## %s\n", tree->childrens[0]->token);
        printf("check token left: %s\n",tree->childrens[0]->token);
        /* send left side to evaluate*/
        s_3AC* e1 = cond3AC(tree->childrens[0]);
        printf("e1 -> %s", e1->code); 
        reset();
        s_3AC* node = (s_3AC*)malloc(sizeof(s_3AC) * 1);
        node->code = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(tree->token) + strlen(e1->code) + strlen(e2->code) + 1));
        strcat(node->code,e1->code);
        strcat(node->code,tree->token);
        strcat(node->code,e2->code);

        node->var = NULL;
        node->falsel = NULL;
        node->truel = NULL;
        return node;

    }else{
        s_3AC* node = (s_3AC*)malloc(sizeof(s_3AC));
        printf("SUCCESS\n");
        node->code = strdup(tree->token);
        node->var = strdup(tree->token);
        node->truel = NULL;
        node->falsel = NULL;

    return node;
}
```

> ```
> s_3AC* cond3AC(node *tree){
>     printf("OKOKOK\n");
>     printf("tree->token: %s\n",tree->token);
>     if(is_kind_of_type(tree->token)){
>         char *code = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(tree->childrens[0]->token) + 1));
>          printf("tree->token after the if: %s\n",tree->token);
>         strcat(code, tree->childrens[0]->token);
>
>         s_3AC* node = (s_3AC*)malloc(sizeof(s_3AC) * 1);
>         node->code = strdup(code);
>         node->var = NULL;
>         node->truel = NULL;
>         node->falsel = NULL;
>         return node;
>     }
>     s_3AC* check = Exp3AC(tree);
>     printf("ˆˆˆˆcheck->codeˆˆˆˆ: %s\n", check->code);
>     return check;
> }
> ```

output:

```
    ######## check now the e2 ########## 
check token right: int
OKOKOK
tree->token: int
tree->token after the if: int
e2 -> 23
######## check now the e1 ########## a
check token left: a
OKOKOK
tree->token: a
SUCCESS
ˆˆˆˆcheck->codeˆˆˆˆ: a
zsh: segmentation fault  ./Part3 < test.t
```

Comment: @WeatherVane I do not understand how this is related?
He falls even before he gets there when he tries to make a placement for e1 he already falls   "s_3AC* e1 = cond3AC(tree->childrens[0]);"

Comment: I moved the comment to an answer, because it is a fault with the code. Perhaps there is a similar fault, or perhaps you pass a `NULL` pointer to a string function, or an unterminated string. The error could be anywhere in the code: memory corruption doesn't always cause an immediate fault.

Answer (score 0):

Consider these lines of code:

```
node->code = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(tree->token) + strlen(e1->code) + strlen(e2->code) + 1));
strcat(node->code,e1->code);
strcat(node->code,tree->token);
strcat(node->code,e2->code);
```

The memory allocated has not been initialised, and the first `strcat` expects there to be a valid C string (an empty one). The function will hunt through memory until it finds a string terminator to begin the append, which may be outside of the memory allocation.

Change the first `strcat` to `strcpy` so

```
node->code = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(tree->token) + strlen(e1->code) + strlen(e2->code) + 1));
strcpy(node->code,e1->code);
strcat(node->code,tree->token);
strcat(node->code,e2->code);
```

Comment: Alternately, could one not leave the `strcat` calls alone and add `node->code[0] = '\0';`, making `node->code` an empty C string?

Comment: You could, if you like the extra line of code.

Comment: I changed but again I do not think there is a connection at the moment to what you are offering and why it falls ...
He literally falls after he comes back he can not even print the line.
printf ("e1 ->% s", e1-> code);

Comment: Sorry about that: you have posted a snippet of code, and I can see a fault with it. Perhaps there is an error in function `red()` or `purple()` or `reset()`.